# Intersection of a locally complete intersection using Tor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, intersection-theory

I just started learning about some basic intersection theory, after an introduction to algebraic geometry. I heard a lecture in which the following was left as an exercise and I cannot understand it so I was hoping for a hint. Suppose that $Z,Z' $ are irreducible subvarieties of of a smooth projective scheme $ Y$ such that $dim(Z)+dim(Z')=dim(Y)$. If $Z,Z'$ is a locally complete intersection, show that, for $i>0$, we have $Tor_i^{O_Y}(O_Z,O_{Z'}) = 0$. Here $O_Z$ is the structure sheaf. I thought possibly to try to show that the morphism from $Z \to Y$ is flat, but that seems wrong.

Comment: Take $Z=Z'$, hypersurface in $Y$. Then $Tor^1\neq 0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I think I am relatively unfamilar with Tor could be the issue here.

Comment: Without knowing how much homological algebra you know, I will not know where to start. If you do not know how to calculate Tor, I would suggest you look it up in a book.

Comment: $Tor_{>0}(O_Z,O_{Z'}) = 0$ if and only if the intersection of $Z$ and $Z'$ is dimensionally transverse. For a proof one can use Koszul complexes. Projectivity of $Y$ is irrelevant.

Comment: I know how to calculate Tor but I think Koszul complexes are unfamiliar to me. Regardless, thank you guys for directing me to the necessary concepts I need to know.